# Java regex to match these strings

Tags: java, regex

I have following 2 urls:

https://docs.google.com/a/abc.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj9Oa8x5fqsL678FNhOUF0ZEN5b25iVVZNdjdUQm9mM1E&usp=drive_web#gid=0

https://docs.google.com/a/abc.com/file/d/0Aj9Oa8x5fqsL678FNhOUF0ZEN5b25iVVZNdjdUQm9mM1E/edit

I am using following regex:

```
Pattern.compile(".*key=|/d/(.[^&/])")
```

as a result of it I want that the `matcher.group()` returns both urls upto `fileId(0Aj9Oa8x5fqsL678FNhOUF0ZEN5b25iVVZNdjdUQm9mM1E)` part and `matcher.group(1)` returns the fileId.

but I am not getting these results.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use a regex? Using `URI` would make your job much easier

Comment: yes I want to know the answer with regex

Comment: Maybe you _want_ to but here regex is very far from being the ideal solution; see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you fell victim to the precedence rules in regex expressions and forgot the repetition specifier for your character class. try

```
Pattern.compile("(key=|/d/)([^&/]+)")
```

your result will be in `$2`.

Comment: just a little change `Pattern.compile(".+(key=|/d/)([^&/]+)")` an it works. I wanted matching pattern too

Answer (score 1):

If you don't *need* to use a regex, then use `URI`:

```
private static final Pattern PARAM_SEPARATOR = Pattern.compile("&");
private static final Pattern PATH_MATCHER = Pattern.compile("/file/d/([^/]+)");

// In query parameter...
public static String getKeyQueryParamFromURI(final String input)
{
    final URI uri = URI.create(input);
    final String params = uri.getQuery();
    if (params == null)
        return null;
    for (final String param: PARAM_SEPARATOR.split(input))
        if (param.startsWith("key="))
            return param.substring(4);
    return null;
}

// In path...
public static String getPathMatcherFromURI(final String input)
{
    final URI uri = URI.create(input);
    final String path = uri.getPath();
    if (path == null)
        return null;
    final Matcher m = PATH_MATCHER.matcher(input);
    return m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
}
```

Note that unlike a regex, you will receive the result *unescaped*. If for instance the URI reads `key=a%20b`, this will return you "a b"!

If you insist on using a regex (why?), then do that instead for the query parameter:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<=[?&])key=([^&]+)");

public static String getKeyQueryParamFromURI(final String input)
{
    final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);
    return m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
}
```

But you'll have to unescape the parameter value yourself...

Comment: your first code snippet wouldn't match the google uri format, would it ? though i concede that *in general*, url segmentation with regexes is a bad idea, it appears well suited for the specific use case (known restricted url format, known relevant context, known restricted content [assuming ascii7 keys are to be extracted which it is safe to assume will not come percent-encoded]).

Comment: @collapsar what do you mean? That I don't check for the scheme, host etc?

Comment: you only check for the `key=` syntax, not for the info being part of the uri's location segment - or am i missing some subtlety?

Answer (score 0):

It's prefer for two different regex pattern to split the regex statement and not use `|`(OR).
With using different pattern you will have the first capture group the result you wanted.

**Pattern1:**

```
.*key=(.*)=.*
```

**Pattern2:**

```
.*\/file\/?\/(.*)\/.*
```